# Dynamically place a user control based on Code Behind (VB.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, code-behind

I have a user control which is essentially a main menu.

I can place it into my MasterPage hard-coded, but I don't want that, I want to be able to dynamically place it with the code behind of the MasterPage.

```
<controls:mainMenu ID='MainMenu1' runat='server' />
```

So what I am looking to do is something like

```
if **condition is true ** _
  response.write('<controls:mainMenu ID='MainMenu1' runat='server' />')
```

Of course, I know that won't work, but how would I place the control based on a condition in code behind on the master page?

I'm using VB by the way, not C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
Dim myControl As Control = CType(Page.LoadControl("yourcontrol.ascx"), Control)
if **condition is true ** _ 
   Panel1.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

You'd need to add a Panel or PlaceHolder control to your page to hold your control.